# Function or macro definition which one to use

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have some macros that I use a lot

So I was thinking in my case would it be better to use a function or use the macro definition?

Example of a macro code that I use:

```
#define Test(Id, TName, i, FName, var1, var2, var3) do { \
    if (GetTable(Id, TName)) { \
        while (i < 5) { \
            if (GetField(Id, FName)) { \
                const char *user = PushName(Id, FName); \
                if (!CheckNameisValid(user)) \
                    continue; \
                var1 = GetTimestamp(user); \
                var2 = GetSex(user); \
                var3 = GetCntLogin(user); \
                i++; \
            } \
        } \
    } \
} while (false);
```

What would be better to use for as per the above code?

Keep using macro definition or migrate to function ?

Comment: That looks like a prime candidate for a true function. (1) It's not doing anything "special" that wouldn't work as a function.  (2) Having to keep all those \ characters in the right margin is a significant nuisance.

Comment: I would say definitely a function. If you have full compiler optimizations active, then the compiler will generally automatically inline all functions, when appropriate.

Comment: I listed two specific considerations in my first comment, but these days, it's just about a no-brainer: There's almost no reason to use function-like macros, ever.  Function-like macros have lots of pitfalls, which true functions avoid.  If you're worried about function call overhead, marking a function `inline` generally takes care of that.

Comment: Additionally this seems like a good candidate for a plain, readable `for` loop without `continue`. Seems fishy not to increment `i` when `continue` hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given how the macro is written, it would be much better to use a function for this purpose.  The macro does not use any construction such as referring to a structure member whose name is passed as an argument to the macro.

The macro has multiple problems:

- variable `i` is assumed to have been declared and initialized appropriately, but it is only incremented if `CheckNameisValid(user)` is non zero, potentially causing an infinite loop.
- the `;` should not be part of the macro expansion to allow usage as a single expression statement.
- it is unclear if the variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3` should be updated once or multiple times, and the caller has no way to tell what actually happened as a side effect of this macro.

Defining functions with clear semantics is much preferred. Don't even worry about inline functions, modern compilers can determine which functions are worth inlining even if not defined as such.

Answer (score 2):

> would it be better to use a function or use the macro definition?

A function.

> What would be better to use for as per the above code?

A function.

> Keep using macro definition or migrate to function ?

Migrate to function.